# How to import IPFS in svelte?

Tags: javascript, svelte-3, ipfs, js-ipfs

I'm trying to import the ipfs like

```
"import {create} from 'ipfs'"
```

but is not working it gives me error like

[image]

upon using the package "ipfs-http-client"

```
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client'
```

[image]

what is the solution for this?

I'm using svelte v3.0 with roll up plugin v7.0.